# Export transactions require a customer name and address - Stripe Issue

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deployment, stripe-payments, mern

I am integrating stripe with nodeJs with order controller, when calling this API on frontend,  i am able to go on stripe checkout page but getting

error: As per Indian regulations, export transactions require a customer name and address. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports

```
const STRIPE = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_API_KEY as string);

type CheckoutSessionRequest = {
  cartItems: {
    menuItemId: string;
    name: string;
    quantity: string;
  }[];
  deliveryDetails: {
    email: string;
    name: string;
    address: string;
    city: string;
  };
  restaurantId: string;
};

const createCheckoutSession = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const checkoutSessionRequest: CheckoutSessionRequest = req.body;

    const restaurant = await Restaurant.findById(checkoutSessionRequest.restaurantId);
    if (!restaurant) {
      throw new Error("Restaurant not found");
    }

    const lineItem = createLineItem(
      checkoutSessionRequest,
      restaurant.menuItems
    );

    const session = await createSession(
      lineItem,
      "TEST_ORDER_ID",
      restaurant.deliveryPrice,
      restaurant._id.toString()
    );

    if (!session.url) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Error creating stripe session" });
    }

    return res.json({ url: session.url }); // Return the session URL

  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.raw.message });
  }
};

const createLineItem = (
  checkoutSessionRequest: CheckoutSessionRequest,
  menuItems: menuItemTypes[]
) => {
  const lineItem = checkoutSessionRequest.cartItems.map((cartItem) => {
    const menuItem = menuItems.find(
      (item) => item._id.toString() === cartItem.menuItemId.toString()
    );

    if (!menuItem) {
      throw new Error(`Menu item not found: ${cartItem.menuItemId}`);
    }

    const line_item: Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateParams.LineItem = {
      price_data: {
        currency: "inr",
        unit_amount: menuItem.price,
        product_data: {
          name: menuItem.name,
        },
      },
      quantity: parseInt(cartItem.quantity),
    };

    return line_item;
  });
  return lineItem;
};

const createSession = async (
  lineItem: Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateParams.LineItem[],
  orderId: string,
  deliveryPrice: number,
  restaurantId: string
) => {
  const sessionData = await STRIPE.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: lineItem,
    shipping_options: [
      {
        shipping_rate_data: {
          display_name: "Delivery",
          type: "fixed_amount",
          fixed_amount: {
            amount: deliveryPrice,
            currency: "inr",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    mode: "payment",
    metadata: {
      orderId,
      restaurantId,
    },
    success_url: `${FRONTEND_URL}/order-status?success=true`,
    cancel_url: `${FRONTEND_URL}/restaurant/${restaurantId}?cancelled=true`,
  });
  return sessionData;
};
```

OnCheckout function (where i pass all data):

```
const onCheckout = async (userFormData: UserFormData) => {
    if (!restaurant) {
      return;
    }

    const checkoutData = {
      cartItems: cartItems.map((cartItem) => ({
        menuItemId: cartItem._id,
        name: cartItem.name,
        quantity: cartItem.quantity.toString(),
      })),
      restaurantId: restaurant._id,
      deliveryDetails: {
        name: userFormData.name,
        addressLine1: userFormData.address,
        city: userFormData.city,
        country: userFormData.country,
        email: userFormData.email as string,
      },
    };

    const data = await createCheckoutSession(checkoutData);
    window.location.href = data.url;
  };
```

I need help, how to do resolve this error.

Comment: Try including https://docs.stripe.com/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-billing_address_collection and set it to `required`

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resloved, i was getting export requires name and address error because i was using wrong test card number(US based), when i used Indian based card number, payment ever done easily.

if you go through such issue, check your country test card number: https://docs.stripe.com/testing#international-cards